# Jetpack compose Scaffolds TopAppBar elevation

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, material3

Trying to add elevation to my TopAppBar in Scaffold topBar. Using Jetpack compose, material 3.

This is how it worked before:

```
TopAppBar(
        title = {
            Text(text = title)
        },
        elevation = 3.dp //Not valid anymore
    )
```

Current allowed parameters in TopAppBar are:

```
public fun TopAppBar(
    title: @Composable () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier,
    navigationIcon: @Composable () -> Unit,
    actions: @Composable() (RowScope.() -> Unit),
    windowInsets: WindowInsets,
    colors: TopAppBarColors,
    scrollBehavior: TopAppBarScrollBehavior?
): Unit
```

This is what I have:

[image: No elevation]

This is what I need:

[image: Have elevation]

It could be done before using parameter to pass elevation but that is not option anymore.

What would be solution to elevate whole TopAppBar?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: As you can check in the M3 [doc](https://m3.material.io/components/top-app-bar/overview#6414ed19-c273-4f32-94d5-5ef782303023):
> **Elevation**: No drop shadow, instead a color fill creates separation from content

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have you tried it with a surface..?

```
Scaffold(topBar = {
    Surface(shadowElevation = 3.dp) {
        SmallTopAppBar(title = {
            Text(
                text = "title"
            )
        })
    }
}) {
// Content
}
```

Check the output :

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Yes that looks like it works good. I can just add padding and have same result. Thank you!

Comment: Do we really need to wrap it additional Surface?

Answer (score 4):

this works very well for me:

```
TopAppBar(modifier = Modifier
            .padding(10.dp)
            .shadow(
                elevation = 5.dp,
                spotColor = Color.DarkGray,
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp)
            ))
```

[image: top appbar with elevation and rounded corners]